# Starting new activity in imageview activity

Tags: android

I had problem with making an Imageview zoom able in android... finally I solved it but greater problem came to me.
This is a part of my code:

```
package com.ctc.android.widget;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ImageMap extends ImageView {

}
```

I need to go to another activity when a button is clicked But as you know the method "start activity(intent , intent)" can not be used in ImageView activities...
My question is "How to create method "StartActivity() in this type of activities"?"
Thank you for reading

Comment: What do you mean by ImageView Activities?

Comment: Well, his class obviously extends an `ImageView`, so I imagine he just mixed up Views with Activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask for a Context object in your View's constructor (or just get the context however you like). Then you can use that object instead of `this` when calling methods like `startActivity()`.